# Webpack-dev-server certificate expired?

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, webpack, webpack-dev-server

In my webpack.config.js file, I added https configuration:

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    https: true
}
```

Then I receive an error when I navigate to https://localhost:8080/

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
Subject: webpack
Issuer: webpack
Expires on: Dec 10, 2015
Current date: Mar 27, 2016
PEM encoded chain: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE----
```

It appears webpack's certificate expired. Did I configure something incorrectly? Or have I misunderstood SSL?

I'm using

```
"webpack": "^1.12.9",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

As pointed by Markus in the comments, webpack-dev-server generates the certificate automatically since version 2.5.0.

---

**OLD ANSWER:**

The problem is that the self-signed certificate of webpack-dev-server expired. This has been fixed in [#436](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/pull/436).

Comment: Does this mean it will work with the next version of webpack-dev-server? I just reinstalled and the current version doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, there's no public release with the fix yet. You could try pointing to the repository version (`webpack/webpack-dev-server`) in the meantime to see if that works for you.

Comment: I can add that since version 2.5.0 of webpack-dev-server, it auto generates the certificate, if one does not exist. If you are using the npm package, you can delete the certificate under node_modules/webkit-dev-server/ssl/server.pem for it to be regenerated.

Comment: @MarkusJarderot Thanks. I altered the answer with that info.